# Convergence with double summation

Tags: statistics, convergence-divergence, summation

I have to prove that these two equations converge:

$$1. \sum_{h=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{h^2} (\sum_{j=1}^{h}\frac{1}{j})^2$$

$$2. \sum_{h=1}^{\infty}|\frac{(-1)^h}{h} \sum_{j=1}^{h}\frac{1}{j}|$$

However, I have never done a convergence test with a double summation before, especially when their indexes depend on eachother.

If someone can explain to me the basic idea behind it, that would me appreciated!

Comment: Please read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/148510) and adhere to [Policy Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/148510).

Comment: This has less to do with convergence tests for double summation and more to do with properties of the sequence $\sum_{j=1}^h \frac{1}{j}$ (partial sum of harmonic series).  Hint: Show that $h^{-1}\sum_{j=1}^h \frac{1}{j}$ is decreasing and note that (2) is an alternating series.

Comment: In series (1), the inner sum grows like $\log h$ (Harmonic sum) he conclusion to this double series follows from standard one-single series.

Comment: @RRL the partial sum of the harmonic series is approximately $ln(h)$, therefore  $\sum_{h=1}^{\infty}|\frac{(-1)^h}{h} (\sum_{j=1}^{h}\frac{1}{j})| =  \sum_{h=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{h} (\sum_{j=1}^{h}\frac{1}{j}) = \sum_{h=1}^{\infty}\frac{ln(h)}{h}$, which diverges from my understanding... I have a hard time seeing how the series decreases. Where was I wrong?

Comment: @baoiba: With the absolute value that is true.  Without the absolute value the series is conditionally convergent.  I assumed the absolute value was a typo -- why include $(-1)^h$ otherwise?

Comment: ... and what is decreasing is $\frac{1}{h}\sum_{j=1}^h \frac{1}{j}$ as $h$ increases -- thereby meeting the monotonicity condition of the AST.